# Angularjs scope variables do not update when changed after http request

Tags: html, angularjs, http

I have a `div` which is supposed to show 3 different `span`s with different messages: one for success, one for loading and one for fail. I have handled it this way:

```
<div class="notifbar">
    <span ng-if="sendingACode == true" class="notif-text">
        sending...wait
    </span>
    <span ng-if="sendingACode == false && sendingSuccessState == 1" class="notif-text">
        successfully sent
    </span>
    <span ng-if="sendingACode == false && sendingSuccessState == 0" class="notif-text mutualAnimationIf">
        failed to send
    </span>
</div>
```

The idea is clear. when `sendingAcode == true`, you are sending. Hance, loading span must be visible. when `sendingAcode == false`, you are done with sending request and you were successful or not.

**I expect this:** you click on the responsible button->loadins msg is shown->your request ends either in success or fail state->fail/success msg is shown and loading msg is hidden->3 seconds pass->all msgs are invisible

**Here's what happens:**  you click on the button->loading msg is shown->request ends and I can see my DB updated->10 seconds or more pass->successful/failed msg is shown and loading msg is hidden. Or nothing happens at all, if you were successful the last time you tried. :|

There is a function that handles sending requests, and here is goes :

```
$scope.sendMyReq = function () {
    $scope.sendingACode=true;//we are in loading state
    $scope.sentFaultCode=code;//data to be sent

    $http.post(UrlConstantsServer.deviceLogsUrl , code)
        .then(function mySuccess(response) {
                console.log("succeed");
                console.log("sending? " + $scope.sendingACode);
                $scope.sendingSuccessState = 1;//show success
                $scope.sendingACode = false;//do not show loading
                console.log("success? " + $scope.sendingSuccessState);

                $timeout (function (){
                    console.log("here in timeout")
                    $scope.sendingACode = false;//no need to show loading msg anymore
                    $scope.sendingSuccessState = -1;//no need to show success/fail msg anymore
                }, 3000)
            }
            , function myFail(response){
                console.log(response) ;
                console.log("unable to send!");
                $scope.sendingSuccessState = 0;//show fail
                $scope.sendingACode = false;//do not show loading

                $timeout (function (){
                    console.log("here in timeout")
                    $scope.sendingACode = false;//no need to show loading msg anymore
                    $scope.sendingSuccessState = -1;//no need to show success or fail msg anymore
                }, 3000)

            });
}
```

**So basically the problem is:** Timeout works way slower than 3 seconds, and even though it is launched, the values it sets do not show effect in view.

**What I have tried:**

- Printing value of my variables in console to check them inside `myScuccess and myFail`: They show the right value.
- Evaluating them in watch of inspect page after the end of request: no solid answer. Sometimes nothing is updated, sometimes everyone is updated, sometimes one is updated and the other is not. :|
- Changing everyone's value inside and outside timeout: outside timeout
  nothing happens. Inside timeout works, but VERY slower than desired.
- Using `$scope.$digest();` at the end of `mySuccess()` and `myFail`:
  Error: $digest already in progress.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: How long do requests take when you inspect them in dev tools? The `$timeout` only starts once request has completed (or failed)

Comment: @charlietfl two or three seconds max. I expect my timeout to start at the end of mySuccess and myFail...it does so, right?

Comment: Are  there any other `ng-if` or `ng-include` or `ng-repeat` involved? All of those create child scopes.  Suggest you use an object for those variables or switch to using `controllerAs` syntax

Comment: @charlietfl This div with `class=notifbar` is a direct child of a div with `ng-include` . And there are some `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` in this page below this div, but they are not related. They are just all children of the mentioned parent div.

Comment: Then try what I suggested due to the child scoping

Comment: @charlietfl by Object you mean a json object?

Comment: There is no such thing as a json object. I mean a javascript object with 3 properties  instead of 3 primitives

Comment: I meant the same :D

Comment: @charlietfl Did as you suggested, here's the result: it takes 18 seconds until the timeout starts and msg changes from loading to successful. But the values are all set correctly. failed msg works nice and fast and no problem occured! Thank you for your help! My main problem is solved and I guess I can handle the slowness. two issues: 1-please send is as answer so I can mark is as accepted. 2- I did not deeply understand why this solved the issue. could you please elaborate it more?

Comment: @charlietfl hello? :D did you receive my last comment? :D